# Creating/replacing a timestamp when a number changes (Google Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a gold spot value on a Google Sheet that automatically updates every 5 minutes. Im trying to write something that will put a timestamp whenever this value changes (every 5 minutes), so people can see the last time the value has been updated. I'm not logging any of these values, only the latest value is relevant to me, and the time it was updated. I don't know how to write a script that detects changes in a single grid, then send a command to update a time somewhere on that same sheet.

I know the line to place the current date, but I do not know how to tell it where to be placed, nor how to connect it to update whenever the spot value changes.

Heres what i'm using to calculate the spot of both gold and silver

```
function getOneOzGoldPriceUsd() {
  var url = "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD";
  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "GET",
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions":true
      };
   var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

   var data = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());

   var goldPrice = data['items'][0]['xauPrice'];


  return goldPrice;
}

function getOneOzSilverPriceUsd() {
  var url = "https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD";
  var options =
      {
        "method"  : "GET",
        "followRedirects" : true,
        "muteHttpExceptions":true
      };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  var data = JSON.parse(result.getContentText());

  var silverPrice = data['items'][0]['xagPrice'];


  return silverPrice;
}

function updateGoldPriceInSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var valuesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutoValueGold");
  var range = valuesSheet.getRange("B1:B1");
  var goldValueCell = range.getCell(1,1)
  goldValueCell.setValue(this.getOneOzGoldPriceUsd());  

  var sc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var valuesSheet = sc.getSheetByName("AutoValueSilver");
  var range = valuesSheet.getRange("B1:B1");
  var silverValueCell = range.getCell(1,1)
  silverValueCell.setValue(this.getOneOzSilverPriceUsd());  
}
```

Comment: How does this value get updated automatically ? Via a trigger or formula ?

Comment: Google script lets me automatically run functions, I have it currently set to run the functions that scans for gold spot from a website every 5 minutes, then chart it into a box. Instead of something that detects change in value, I could throw something in this same function that displays and places the current time. I sadly don't know hot to do that either though.

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean automatically? Do you have a trigger ? Do you have a formula ? What is a gold spot ? Improve your answer so the community can help you. Help us to help you is the idea :)

Comment: You can also share a screenshot of your sheet or even a copy of your sheet and describe to us step by step what you want to achieve .

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know what a trigger is, my knowledge in coding is just very basic java. I just know that I can tell Google to repeat any function in my code, at any time interval, forever (if thats what a trigger is). "spot" is the exact value of a metal based on the universal stock exchange, mainly Chicago; that updates every second (though i'm only recording the changes every 5 minutes though). I added the current code to my post

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a time-driven function that updates `goldValueCell` and `silverValueCell` you can just include in `updateGoldPriceInSheet()` a line of code to update the cell with the timestamp of the update.

Assuming that you want to update the value of **B1** with the timestamp of the update of cell **A1**, `updateGoldPriceInSheet()` can be modified like that:

```
function updateGoldPriceInSheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var valuesSheet = ss.getSheetByName("AutoValueGold");
  var range = valuesSheet.getRange("B1:B1");
  var goldValueCell = range.getCell(1,1)
  goldValueCell.setValue(this.getOneOzGoldPriceUsd());  
  
  //Update a cell with the timestamp
  valuesSheet.getRange('B1').setValue(new Date()) 

  var sc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var valuesSheet = sc.getSheetByName("AutoValueSilver");
  var range = valuesSheet.getRange("B1:B1");
  var silverValueCell = range.getCell(1,1)
  silverValueCell.setValue(this.getOneOzSilverPriceUsd());  

}
```

Likewise you can do exactly the same for `silverValueCell` if you want to.

Comment: op says  it's a time trigger. Don't think a simple onEdit will work.

Comment: I updated my answer with a much more clever approach. He can just update the cell value from his current time-driven trigger function.

Comment: The first part is still wrong though. onEdit won't work when another script edits a cell.

Comment: thanks for the info. I didn't know that and I assumed that onEdit() worked because he accepted my answer. Thanks again for the information.